# Python if does not behave as expected

Tags: python

I was trying to make a python calculator. But for some reason it will only output the square-root option.
I am currently using python3.4 and 3.3 emulator on my iPhone, but it has the same problem on both devices.

```
print("This program is a calculator app \n Creator: AtPython")
print("...")
Print("please choose a       mathematical operation")
Opt = input("square-root. \n addition, \n subtraction, \n multiplication, \n division: ")

if opt == "square-root" or "squareroot":
    num = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    num_sqrt = num ** 0.5
    print('The square root of %0.3f is %0.3f'%(num ,num_sqrt))
    input("Press 'Enter' to exit")

If opt == "addition":
    add_1 = float(input("Please enter a number"))
    add_2 = float(input("Please enter another number")) 
    add_ans = add_1 + add_2
    print(add_ans)
    qus = input("Would you like to add   another number? [y/n]")
    
elif qus == "y":
    add_3 = float(input("Enter a third number"))
    input("Press 'Enter' to exit")
    
else:
    input("Press 'Enter' to exit")
```

Comment: You have numerous syntax errors in the code you posted. Not sure if those are present in the original or if they were misformatted on SO.

Comment: @Ming only the indentation and some punctuation was changed.

Comment: Can you please fix your whitespacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if opt == "square-root" or "squareroot":
```

This does not parse as `if opt == "square-root" or opt == "squareroot":` This parses as `if (opt == "square-root") or bool("squareroot")`, which returns `True` because calling `bool` on a string is always `True` unless the string is empty. (see [link](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/boolean.html) for more info)

The fix would be:

```
if opt == "square-root" or opt == "squareroot":
```

or

```
if opt in ["square-root","squareroot"]:
```